# jQuery "growl-like" effect in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hey all, i have made a simple form that mimiks the jQuery "GROWL" effect seen here http://www.sandbox.timbenniks.com/projects/jquery-notice/

However, i have ran into a problem. If i have more than one call to the form to display a "Growl" then it just refreshes the same form with whatever call i send it. In other words, i can only display one form at a time instead of having one drop down and a new one appear above it.

Here is my simple form code for the "GROWL" form:

```
Public Class msgWindow
Public howLong As Integer
Public theType As String
Private loading As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal pe As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim pn As New Pen(Color.DarkGreen)

    If theType = "OK" Then
        pn.Color = Color.DarkGreen
    ElseIf theType = "ERR" Then
        pn.Color = Color.DarkRed
    Else
        pn.Color = Color.DarkOrange
    End If

    pn.Width = 2
    pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pn, 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
    pn = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub showMessageBox(ByVal typeOfBox As String, ByVal theMessage As String)
    Me.Opacity = 0
    Me.Show()
    Me.SetDesktopLocation(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 350, 15)

    Me.loading = True
    theType = typeOfBox
    lblSaying.Text = theMessage

    If typeOfBox = "OK" Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 192)
    ElseIf typeOfBox = "ERR" Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192)
    Else
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192)
    End If

    If Len(theMessage) <= 30 Then
        howLong = 4000
    ElseIf Len(theMessage) >= 31 And Len(theMessage) <= 80 Then
        howLong = 7000
    ElseIf Len(theMessage) >= 81 And Len(theMessage) <= 100 Then
        howLong = 12000
    Else
        howLong = 17000
    End If

    Me.opacityTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub opacityTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles opacityTimer.Tick
    If Me.loading Then
        Me.Opacity += 0.07

        If Me.Opacity >= 0.8 Then
            Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
            Me.opacityTimer.Dispose()
            Pause(howLong)
            Me.loading = False
            Me.opacityTimer.Start()
        End If
    Else
        Me.Opacity -= 0.08

        If Me.Opacity <= 0 Then
            Me.opacityTimer.Stop()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Pause(ByVal Milliseconds As Integer)
    Dim dTimer As Date

    dTimer = Now.AddMilliseconds(Milliseconds)

    Do While dTimer > Now
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Sub
End Class
```

I call the form by this simple call:

```
Call msgWindow.showMessageBox("OK", "Finished searching images.")
```

Does anyone know a way where i can have the same setup but would allow me to add any number of forms without refreshing the same form over and over again?

Like always, any help would be great! :)

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it, although there are probably better ways of managing it than this.

```
Public Class Growl

Private _notifications As New Dictionary(Of Integer, msgWindow)
Private _count As Integer = 0

Public Sub Remove(ByVal Sender As msgWindow, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    _notifications.Remove(CInt(Val(Sender.Name.Substring(1))))
    RefreshPositions()
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshPositions()
    Dim _top As Integer = 15
    For a As Integer = 0 To _count
        If _notifications.ContainsKey(a) Then
            _notifications.Item(a).Top = _top
            _top += _notifications.Item(a).Height + 20
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub ShowMessageBox(ByVal typeOfNotification As String, ByVal msg As String)
    Dim x As New msgWindow
    x.Name = "m" & _count
    AddHandler x.FormClosed, AddressOf Remove
    _notifications(_count) = x
    _count += 1
    x.showMessageBox(typeOfNotification, msg)
    RefreshPositions()
End Sub

End Class
```

In your code, declare:

```
Dim g as New Growl
```

and call

```
g.showMessageBox( ... , ... )
```

instead of

```
msgWindow.showMessageBox( ... , ... )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked fine Soumya92 but it doesnt allow each box to stay up. As an exanple, if i had 3 boxes show up 5 seconds behind each other then i would like the first box to fade out, then 5 seconds later the 2nd box fade out and then the final box fade out after 5. Currently they all fade out.

Comment: Any help with the previous problem?